# Is there a way to get popular feeds for 1-week back or 1-month back?

Tags: discussion, rss

I'm finding it very helpful to read through many current posts on the C# and R questions.  I actually read several topics, but the two mentioned above get so many posts each and every day it is literally impossible to click through each title.  I'm looking for a way to set a date range and just quickly browse through all topics for that group between a specified date range, or even this week, last week, last month, etc.  Is there a way to view these posts so I don't need to click on each title?  Simply hitting the up and down arrow keys, as I read through countless posts, would be infinitely easier.

I'm looking specifically at these links.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23

If I click on the 'newest r questions feed' it seems to give me exactly what I'm looking for, but it cuts off after a few hours.  I'd love to get this for 1-week, or even 1-month increments.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You could try SEDE. It's only updated every week, but this probably isn't a problem in your case.

Comment: Can you post a link with a little more description?  I found some info about Stack Exchange Data Explorer, but that doesn't seem to be what I want, unless I did it wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/482452/tag-feed?tag1=r

Comment: you could just setup tag RSS feeds in Feedly and not worry about hacking anything

Answer (score 1):

I setup Outlook and added an RSS feed and it does almost exactly what I want.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1319-outlook-add-remove-rss-feeds.html

The only thing it doesn't do is go back in time.  That's fine.  I can capture all posts from now, going forward.  That will give me PLENTY to read!!

Thanks everyone.